# get a view page using jquery in mvc4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Hi I am working with mvc4

I have a razor view page for the action

```
  public ActionResult DeliveryAddress(string userid,int productid)
    {

       ....
        return View(m);
    }
```

that contain

```
<div ><a href="" class="btn btn-primary" id="place-order">DELIVER HERE</a></div>
```

when clicking on this i am collecting somedata ifrom this page using jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
$("#place-order").click(function () {
    var userid = $('#selected-userId').html();
    var productid = $('#selected-productId').html();


   $.get("Products/PlaceOrder/"+ userid, function (data) { });
});
```

});

and i want to pen another view of action

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult PlaceOrder(int uid)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

and paste the variable content,

but `$.get("Products/PlaceOrder", function (data) { });` is not hitting this action..

please help me.

Comment: Lot of details seems to be missing, how u passing data to the url?

Comment: @ssilas777:currently i just want to hit the controller action thats why i write the code like that

Comment: But unless you provided all details, no one can nail the actual issue, the way you pass the parameters may even cause the issue rit.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you need to pass a data to a url in Jquery get method, note the same parameter name is used in the function

```
  $.get('@Url.Action("PlaceOrder","Products")', { uid: userid }, function (data)
  { 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add HTTPGET attribute in your action method as below.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PlaceOrder()
{
    return View();
}
```

java script

```
$("#place-order").click(function () {
    var userid = $('#selected-userId').html(); // $('#selected-userId').val();

    $.get('@Url.Action("PlaceOrder","Products", new { uid = userid })', function (data) { });

    var productid = $('#selected-productId').html();
});
```

Comment: Did you check with alert for. to check is that place-order on click is triggering or not like this $("#place-order").click(function () { alert('OK'); });

Comment: Try like the update code now. HTTPGET attribute is must in you action method.

Comment: Try now Please, Surely it will helps

Comment: $('#selected-userId').html();  is wrong i thing, may be it should be $('#selected-userId').val(); . Please check its value with alert.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your URL is correct. Most probably use @Url.Action(). and also pass the parameter using new as shown below.

```
    $.get('@Url.Action("PlaceOrder","Products",new { userid  =  @userid  , productid  =  @productid   })', function (data) { 

    });
```

While collecting the data make sure your parameter names are same for both while sending and while receiving.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult PlaceOrder(int userid, int productid )
    {
    return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I want my view code to be fetched like that, or even through the `Html.Action()` call, I use the `PartialView` and normally set my Controller Action as:

```
public ActionResult PlaceOrder(int uid)
{
    return PartialView(new TestViewModel() { ID = uid });
}
```

as an example:

`TestViewModel`

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

`PlaceOrder.cshtml`

```html
@model TestViewModel

<h2>Partial View</h2>
<p>
    Partial View paragraph with the id <b>@Model.ID</b>
</p>
```

`Index.html`

```html
<hr />

@Html.Action("PartialView", "Home", new { id = 44 })

<hr />

<div class="ap"></div>

<script>
    var url = '@Url.Action("PartialView", "Home")';
    $.get(url, { id: 54 }, function (data) {
        $(".ap").append(data);
    });
</script>
```

result:

[image]